# Non Azure VPS connecting to an Azure SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, vps, azure

Ive got a VPS running a web application where its performance is being slowed incredibly by the SQL Server that is installed alongside it. I want to use Azure SQL Server to host the database there and the Application on the VPS that is external to Azure.

Ive published the Database and its data to Azure nicely from the VPS, added the IP address of the VPS on the allowed connection list in the firewall, however when I go to use the connectionstring, I get the usual no permissions or Database does not exist..

Im relatively new to Azure services (Used visual studio to connect and configured virtual machines etc..)so what more do I need to do in order to allow this External VPS to connect and access the SQL Server on Azure?

Answer (score 3):

Setting aside the fact that you can't connect to your Azure database from the application on your VPS, do you think this will actually improve performance?

You haven't specified who your VPS provider is, but it sounds like they will be in completely different datacenters. Who knows, they could even be in completely different continents! The latency you introduce might make the response times of your application even worse.

To me it sounds like you're moving the problem rather than fixing it. If your SQL database is performaing badly, you should probably look at finding the cause of the performance issue and either beefing up your current VPS or splitting out to a new VPS with the same provider.

Comment: I of course agree; but just for the record, you can connect to an Azure database from *anywhere*, as long as you have proper credentials and your IP address is allowed (see my answer). There's nothing (apart from common sense) blocking you from using an Azure database remotely, be it from your LAN or from another hosted server.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to connect remotely to an Azure database, you have to follow these guidelines: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ee336282.aspx.

That said, I agree with [john](https://serverfault.com/users/95312/john): if your application is slow, having it connect to a remote database hosted on a different hosting provider than your VPS (in this case, Azure) is very likely to *reduce* performance, instead of improving it.

Comment: Both the Azure server and the VPS are located in the WEstern Europe Region (Germany specifically).  The application running is NopCommerce on a 2GB dual core VPS.  My perception is that this server is a little gutless for what I need it to do.  Any views??  Azur has increased the load performance on the web application but not that much...

Comment: The region doesn't matter, they would still be in different datacenters; it would be the same if one application server in your own network was querying an Azure database, or vice-versa: they would still have high network latency, much higher than if they were both in the same place (be it your LAN, Azure, or anything else). You really don't want to add f.e. 100ms of network latency to a 10-ms SQL query.